# Displaying message in login page after updating password in PHP

Tags: php, change-password

I have a password update system which is working just fine. But, the problem is I can't show any success message like 'Password Changed!'. Because, after password updates my system redirects the user to logout page which in turn redirects to the login page. I want to show this message in the login page only after password update. I can't try to put and catch a message from $_SESSION variable since when logging out session is getting destroyed. I would appreciate any good idea on this topic. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: I believe I explained enough without the code.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Thanks. It was my first question. So don't know the 'How to Ask' stuffs. I will definitely go through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few ideas:

1) Use a Cookie instead of the $_SESSION (which will indeed be destroyed after starting a new session). If the cookie is set, display you display the message (and delete the cookie)

2) Do not redirect immediately to the login page, but just say: "Password changed! Click here to log in again.". But you can destroy the session on that page safely.

3) Do not destroy the session at all. The fact that the password is changed doesn't mean you have to destroy the session. If your session contains something like: `$_SESSION['validUser'] = 'Y'` that is maybe enough?

Comment: 1. I don't want to use cookie for this case. 2. Already doing this. 3. I want the user to login again after updating. So, destroying existing session.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. A cookie seems to be the best solution in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Erwin Moller's suggestions are all good suggestions and all easily implementable. I think those are the best way(s) to go about it, but if you don't want to use any of those methods, then you could relay a `$_GET` variable from one redirect to another in either a plain message or a value that represents a message:

```
$red_url = 'http://www.example.com/?msg=Password+has+been+reset';
header("Location: {$red_url}");
exit;
```

Make sure to use something like `htmlspecialchars()` or equivalent when outputting the message. This would take care of malicious code insertion, but this method still allows the end user the most flexibility to mess with your site messaging.

The variable method would be similar:

```
$red_url = 'http://www.example.com/?msg=1234';
header("Location: {$red_url}");
exit;
```

on the display page use some way to fetch or translate the `msg` code:

```
<?php if(!empty($_GET['msg']) && is_numeric($_GET['msg'])): ?>
<h3 class="site-message"><?php echo myCodeToMessageFunc($_GET['msg']) ?></h3>
<?php endif ?>
```

The most that can happen is that a user can relay a different code manually to get a different message to appear.

> ** These 2 methods can be messed around with by the user *(harmlessly if you are scrubbing or controlling the output)* so that is why a cookie or session is better, but this is a pretty straight forward messaging method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am going to accept the 'cookie' method that Erwin Moller suggested. That's ok.